# How to make GitIgnore file when app is already on GitHub?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gitignore

From the title of my question you can see what my problem is. I have an app on GitHub but I don't have `.gitnore` file. Now I want to make that file. I read somewhere that I must delete some files with terminal(Ubuntu) and then to make new `.gitnore` file.

Could someone tell me how to do all that stuff?

---

EDIT: I followed a solution from another question but when I write it into the terminal I received this:

```
dev3@dev3-All-Series:~$ git rm --cached
```

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

`dev3@dev3-All-Series:~$`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the files on your local machine, and push to the repository. If the files are removed there, thén you can make the `.gitnore` file. That way, you don't end up with useless 'dead' folders or files on your repo. This way you don't need local access to the files, just your *git* client.

If you add the `.gitnore` first, you won't be able to delete the files because they will be ignored :).

---

If you already have a `.gitnore` file setup, you can do the following to remove files:

You can remove them from the repository manually:

```
git rm --cached file1 file2 dir/file3
```

Or, if you have a lot of files:

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`
```

But this doesn't seem to work in Git Bash on Windows. It produces an error message. The following works better:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs git rm --cached
```

[(found that solution here)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13541721/edit)